# How to calculate distance to polygon edge to compute building setbacks?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop

I'm trying to calculate building setbacks using building footprint data. A building setback is the distance between a building and the edge of the lot line. (You can distinguish this further—garage setback and structure setback, but I won't complicate things.) The image below (red lines) shows the distance I am trying to get for one of the blocks as an example.

[image: building setbacks]

I have no idea how to start this. I think I need to turn the footprint and parcel polygons into polylines and break at vertices? I want to use the street center-line (green) as a sort of magnet so that the distance is calculated to the *front* of the lot instead of the back or side. I can ignore corner lots for the time being.

BTW, the parcels are also dissolved so it is just block structure (pic below). That means I just need to find the shortest distance between the footprint polygon and the edge of the block polygon.

[image: block structure]

If anyone has any clue, please let me know! This is for a class project. (And I'm using ArcGIS and QGIS.)

Comment: There was a similar post [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127824/qgis-equivalent-for-arcmap-join-for-purpose-of-distances-from-points-to-polygon) which might be of some help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, manually construct a huge polygon around all your light gray parcels. 
Then [erase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000m000000) the parcels from the huge polygon. Now [convert the light grey parcels to lines](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003t000000).

Once you have these layers, select by location the lines of the light grey parcels that share a line segment with your erased huge polygon. Export these selected lines into a new layer.

Finally, run the [near](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001q000000) tool with your black polygons and the resulting lines. That's the distance you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try this, but my concern is that it doesn't seem to be replicable across, say, an entire city. And that's what I'm trying to do. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to do it with a hole city just make the polygon big enough to surround your city. I don't see what is the problem.